# file does not exist - spark submit

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to launch a spark application using this command:

```
time spark-submit --master "local[4]" optimize-spark.py
```

But I got these errors:

```
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
16/01/27 15:43:32 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 1.6.0
16/01/27 15:43:32 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
16/01/27 15:43:32 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: DamianFox
16/01/27 15:43:32 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: DamianFox
16/01/27 15:43:32 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users with view permissions: Set(DamianFox); users with modify permissions: Set(DamianFox)
16/01/27 15:43:33 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 51613.
16/01/27 15:43:33 INFO Slf4jLogger: Slf4jLogger started
16/01/27 15:43:33 INFO Remoting: Starting remoting
16/01/27 15:43:33 INFO Remoting: Remoting started; listening on addresses :[akka.tcp://sparkDriverActorSystem@192.168.0.102:51614]
16/01/27 15:43:33 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriverActorSystem' on port 51614.
16/01/27 15:43:33 INFO SparkEnv: Registering MapOutputTracker
16/01/27 15:43:33 INFO SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMaster
16/01/27 15:43:33 INFO DiskBlockManager: Created local directory at /private/var/folders/8m/h5qcvjrn1bs6pv0c0_nyqrlm0000gn/T/blockmgr-defb91b0-50f9-45a7-8e92-6d15041c01bc
16/01/27 15:43:33 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 511.1 MB
16/01/27 15:43:33 INFO SparkEnv: Registering OutputCommitCoordinator
16/01/27 15:43:33 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4040.
16/01/27 15:43:33 INFO SparkUI: Started SparkUI at http://192.168.0.102:4040
16/01/27 15:43:33 ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Added file file:/Project/MinimumFunction/optimize-spark.py does not exist.
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.addFile(SparkContext.scala:1364)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.addFile(SparkContext.scala:1340)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$15.apply(SparkContext.scala:491)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$15.apply(SparkContext.scala:491)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:491)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:59)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:234)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:381)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:214)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:68)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:209)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
16/01/27 15:43:34 INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://192.168.0.102:4040
16/01/27 15:43:34 INFO MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!
16/01/27 15:43:34 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
16/01/27 15:43:34 INFO BlockManager: BlockManager stopped
16/01/27 15:43:34 INFO BlockManagerMaster: BlockManagerMaster stopped
16/01/27 15:43:34 WARN MetricsSystem: Stopping a MetricsSystem that is not running
16/01/27 15:43:34 INFO OutputCommitCoordinator$OutputCommitCoordinatorEndpoint: OutputCommitCoordinator stopped!
16/01/27 15:43:34 INFO SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
16/01/27 15:43:34 INFO RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator: Shutting down remote daemon.
16/01/27 15:43:34 INFO RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator: Remote daemon shut down; proceeding with flushing remote transports.
16/01/27 15:43:34 INFO RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator: Remoting shut down.
ERROR - failed to write data to stream: <open file '<stdout>', mode 'w' at 0x10bb6e150>

16/01/27 15:43:34 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
16/01/27 15:43:34 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /private/var/folders/8m/h5qcvjrn1bs6pv0c0_nyqrlm0000gn/T/spark-c00170ca-0e05-4ece-a962-f9303bce4f9f
spark-submit --master "local[4]" optimize-spark.py  6.12s user 0.52s system 187% cpu 3.539 total
```

How can I fix this? Is it something wrong on the variables? It's been a lot of time that I'm searching but I cannot find a solution. Thanks!

Comment: Where have you placed optimize-spark.py ??

Comment: I've placed optimize-spark.py inside the folder where I run the command

Comment: try adding `--py-files` as argument to `spark-submit`

Comment: @Sumit can you provide an example?

Comment: `spark-submit --master "local[4]" --py-files optimize-spark.py`

Comment: I've tried the commando above, but now I got this error: Error: `Must specify a primary resource (JAR or Python or R file)`

Comment: @Sumit do you know what I am missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I move the project folder to the desktop folder and now it is working. 
Probably it wasn't working before, because I put the project in a folder whose name has spaces, therefore the command, very likely, didn't find the file.

Comment: yes, I was experiencing same kind of problems, permissions was OK but folder name where the file was located had spaces and this break spark submit.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for the confusion. `--py-files` is used for providing additional dependent python files needed by your program, so that they can be placed in `PYTHONPATH`. 
I tried again following command works for me in windows/ Spark-1.6: -

```
bin\spark-submit --master "local[4]" testingpyfiles.py
```

`testingpyfiles.py` is a simple python file which prints some random data on the console and is stored in the same directory from where I am executing the above mentioned command. Here is code for `testingpyfiles.py`

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf

conf = SparkConf().setAppName("Python App")
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)

data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
distData = sc.parallelize(data)
print("Now it will print the data")
print(distData)
```

In your case it seems that either path is not correct or there may be some issues with the privileges for executing the file. Also ensure that `optimize-spark.py` is located in the same directory where we are executing `spark-submit`.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem in two ways:

1. You can pass the file as an argument to `--py-files` like so,

   ```
   spark-submit --master "local[4]" --py-files="<filepath>/optimize-spark.py" optimize-spark.py
   ```

with the `filepath` being the path on the local filesystem.

2. You can dump `optimize-spark.py` file onto HDFS and add it via your code

   ```
   sc.addFile("hdfs:<filepath_on_hdfs>/optimize-spark.py")
   ```